# Migrating ASP.NET Framework v4 Application - Issue Related to Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo

Tags: asp.net, .net, sql-server

I have an ASP.NET Framework v4 web application that is running on Windows Server 2012. I am migrating this application to Windows Server 2019.

My issue is on the new server with `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll`. The application communicates with a SQL Server database and includes reference to `Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll` in `web.config`.

When loading the app in the browser I get an error message that says:

> the located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference

The DLL exists in the `Bin` folder of the app. I checked the `PublicKeyToken` of `Microsoft.SQLServer.ConnectionInfo` and it matches what is in `web.config`.

The closest error someone had that I could find was related to one's development environment. I tried installing the `SQLSysClrTrypes.msi` for SQL Server 2017, which looked like SQL Server v14.

I also recycled the application pool and deleted the `Temporary ASP.NET Files`.

```
Server Error in '/App' Application.
Configuration Error
Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=14.0.17277.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Source Error:


Line 29:       <assemblies>
Line 30:         <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
Line 31:         <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=14.0.17277.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
Line 32:         <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
Line 33:         <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />

Source File: C:\inetpub\App\web.config    Line: 31

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why the assembly 'Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=14.0.17277.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91' could not be loaded.


=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: DisplayName = Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=14.0.17277.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///C:/inetpub/App/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = C:\inetpub\App\bin
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: Using application configuration file: C:\inetpub\App\web.config
LOG: Using host configuration file: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=14.0.17277.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/App/91e1c2f2/661ab1e8/Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v4.0.30319/Temporary ASP.NET Files/App/91e1c2f2/661ab1e8/Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo/Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///C:/inetpub/App/bin/Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.DLL.
WRN: Comparing the assembly name resulted in the mismatch: Minor Version
ERR: Failed to complete setup of assembly (hr = 0x80131040). Probing terminated.

Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.8.4494.0
```

Assemblies referenced in `web.config`:

```xml
<assemblies>
  <add assembly="System.Data.Linq, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
  <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo, Version=14.0.17277.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
  <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
  <add assembly="Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845DCD8080CC91" />
  <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" />
  <add assembly="System.Data.Services.Client, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=B77A5C561934E089" />
</assemblies>
```